# MFC Modify the dialog size created by resource

Tags: mfc

I created a dialog using MFC Dialog application. This is using the dialog resource. And my resource file is as below

```
IDD_My_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 233, 273
WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_EX_STATICEDGE | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1Q
```

Now, at runtime I am receiving the dialog width and height. So as per the width and height I need to change this dialog size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function call below:

```
MoveWindow(int x, int y, int Width, int Height);
```

Or, first get the Dialog coordinates:

```
CRect rc;
GetWindowRect(&rc); // getting dialog coordinates
MoveWindow(rc.left, rc.top, rc.Width(), rc.Height());
```

You can also use `SetWindowPos()` function.

Comment: @LokanathNayak, Your wlcm. You can accept this answer if you find it helpful.